# How to print only selected diagram elements (EA)

Tags: printing, diagram, enterprise-architect

I'm using Enterprise Architect in version 9.2 (OS Windows7).
And I tried to print only a selected class diagram.
But for what ever reason it is not possible to choose this option within the printer dialog.
I do see the option but it is greyed out.

So is there trick how I may able to print only the marked/selected classes?

Appreciate your help
Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems not possible to print the selected classes.

What you can do is:

- select the classes from the diagram
- copy do clipboard - ctrl-c
- add a new class diagram to the model (name it "for printing only" :) )
- paste the classes - ctrl-v
- print it

Any updates to the original class relationship and properties are preserved between diagrams

Comment: Thank you, this is a way I may go.

Comment: I think it's the right way because each diagram should have a purpose and specially in huge models only parts are presented in particular diagrams. So it's worth keeping various diagrams of the same classes for various purposes/audiences/stakeholders